# Google Calendar - getDefaultCalendar - no Authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

[CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar() authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079111/calendarapp-getdefaultcalendar-authorization)

I have a similiar problem like the one below. As described in the answer, I started the jobs from script editor and granted the permissions. But I still get the error in my stackdriver error list and the action is not completed. 
What can I do to authorize the script again or to get it running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar() authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079111/calendarapp-getdefaultcalendar-authorization)

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment it´s not a duplicate. I already started the scripts from script editor and granted the permission.